# Android How to parse JSON file using FlatBuffers?

Tags: android, json, parsing, deserialization, flatbuffers

I am trying to deserialize JSON file stored in memory location.I successfully created required POJOs using flatC compiler but when I when am passing ByteBuffer created for JSON file to the root of pojo I am getting IndexOutOfBoundsException.

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=83946924, limit=1684, size of type=4

for Byte Array conversion from JSON file

```
    if(file != null) {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1; ) {
            bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
        }
        fis.close();
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }
```

This is how I am creating ByteBuffer

ByteBuffer bb = new ByteBuffer().wrap(input[]);

Can any one please let me know where I am missing?

Comment: Why don't you print the contents of input[], and compare it against a dump of the FlatBuffer file you converted from JSON to see where the problem starts?

Answer (score 1):

see JSON parsing with FlatBuffers in Android.

http://frogermcs.github.io/json-parsing-with-flatbuffers-in-android/

I hope this is what you wanted :)

Comment: Thanks Avi, I followed that example. When i load file from RAW folder ever things works perfectly but when I am passing file from Memory location it doesn't work.(I debugged to make sure file contents are available.Those are there).